# Bearer token in GET() authorization in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, get, authorization, bearer-token

I create shiny app which use request to get data. Shiny App and API is secured by the same auth0, so I am tring to write GET() function to get data using Bearer token for authorization but all the time I get 401 (Unauthorized). I also created file _auth0.yml (based on [LINK](https://curso-r.github.io/auth0/))

When I run `session$userData$auth0_credentials` I get:

```
$access_token
[1] "EBI9..."

$id_token
[1] "eyJh..."

$scope
[1] "openid profile"

$expires_in
[1] 01234

$token_type
[1] "Bearer"
```

I run:

```
GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", session$userData$auth0_credentials$access_token)))
```

but I get 401. Then how should it authorize to get data from resquest?

Comment: I haven't used the auth0 package so I probably won't be tons of help here, but just a general pointer: You should not be posting your credentials in plain text on SO, or any other site for that matter.

Comment: @MattKaye, thanks, I edited post

Comment: @tomsu Just as an FYI (not sure how relevant this still is in 2021), everyone can access the Editing history and still find the API key. Hope you updated the key :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I had to add audience parameter in auth0_config section (_auth0.yml file)